# How is MSBuild Incremental Building Different from Copy with SkipUnchangedFiles=true?

Tags: msbuild, copy, incremental-build

If I have an msbuild target that just copies changed files, why would incremental building be better than just using the Copy task and setting SkipUnchangedFiles = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who said it would be?

The only reason I can think of would be if you extended your target later on to perform other tasks then just copying.

Comment: That makes sense. Is the example of incremental building in your msbuild book (p.165) get any benefit from not just being a straight copy? Or, is it just a basic example for the purpose of illustration?

Comment: Yeah that was just to keep the example simple. In that case it would be the same.